# Trying to remember a YA race-type thing book

Tags: story-identification, young-adult

The main character is female, and she has to take part in a race to get some cure for her mom (I think). At the beginning, she gets some kind of message, letters I think, and leaves her house without her parents permission. All the participants get an egg, I think, that hatches a creature. The male love interest is named 'Guy'. I'm pretty sure she doesn't win the race and her creature that hatched died. It was a series of books, I think its probably a trilogy, with the titles being 2 of the locations of the part of the race that occurs in the book.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Fire & Flood by Victoria Scott

Synopsis:

> Tella Holloway is losing it. Her brother is sick, and when a dozen
> doctors can't determine what's wrong, her parents decide to move to
> the middle of nowhere for the fresh air. She's lost her friends, her
> parents are driving her crazy, her brother is dying--and she's
> helpless to change anything.
>
> Until she receives mysterious instructions on how to become a
> Contender in the Brimstone Bleed. It's an epic race across jungle,
> desert, ocean, and mountain that could win her the prize she
> desperately desires: the Cure for her brother's illness. But all the
> Contenders are after the Cure for people they love, and there's no
> guarantee that Tella (or any of them) will survive the race.
>
> The jungle is terrifying, the clock is ticking, and Tella knows she
> can't trust the allies she makes. And one big question emerges: Why
> have so many fallen sick in the first place?
>
> Victoria Scott's breathtaking novel grabs readers by the throat and
> doesn't let go.
>
> [Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/22571272-fire-flood)

A reviewer mentions an egg and Guy:

> I loved when Tella got there, got her egg and got on with where they
> had to start the game. And I fell in love with her Pandora, which
> comes from the egg they get in the beginning, he was a little fox, but
> he has some things he can do :)
>
> I loved Guy, he ended up being Tella's love interest and his pandora
> was a lion.

Found by googling: young adult fantasy novel guy "race" egg